# iOS Objective-C get direct link to YouTube Video for Download

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, xcode6

I want  to  copy  my  favorite  YouTube video link and  paste  it  on my  UITextField from  internet,  and then just download  the  Video and save it to  my  iPhone  Video  folder on button click,  is  that  possible? Any idea, how do i  do  this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube not provides direct link to videos. To get direct link you have to extract YouTube video link by using third party libraries like

**PSYouTubeExtractor**

**XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController**

But you should know that

```
Downloading YouTube content is not in compliance with the YouTube Tearms of Service.
```

If you download and store youtube video in your app, this may be a cause of your app rejection from store.
To read more see **section 5B** here --   http://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms

Comment: even if i want to save the videos on my iPhone? (not in App)

Comment: than private use its ok? cause its just for me

Comment: If you don't want to make your app live than its OK.

Comment: fantastic, thank you. Can you help me with the code?

Comment: Sorry, man but i think these libraries has enough code to solve your problem. Please search for those.

Comment: I tried looking into the codes I found online but I'm a bit confused, I think I need a step-by-step-well-explained reference.

Comment: @Student, if I only extract direct link to video and play it via `MPMoviePlayerController` or any replacement, will app be rejected from **App Store**?